# Not able to add elements at index position in numpy array

Tags: python-3.x

```
from numpy import *
arr1 = array([2,8,9,7],int)
arr2 = array([1,3,5,9],int)


arr3 = array([],int)
for i in range(len(arr1)):
    arr3[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i]

print(arr3)
```

getting an error IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0.Also tried

```
arr3 = array([],int)
for i in range(len(arr1)):
    res = arr1[i] + arr2[i]
    arr3.append(res)
```

but still not works for me.please help . I am a beginner in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While iterating over a array in numpy, at the first approach since you have a empty array you can't assign it through index that's why it throws an index error

For the first approach you can assign the arr3 with zeros

```
from numpy import *
arr1 = array([2,8,9,7])
arr2 = array([1,3,5,9])


arr3 = array([0,0,0,0],int)
print(arr1[0]+arr2[0])
for i in range(len(arr1)):
    arr3[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i]

Output :
[ 3 11 14 16 ]
```

At the Second approach in numpy array the way you used the append is not the correct way of using numpy.append()

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
arr1 = array([2,8,9,7])
arr2 = array([1,3,5,9])
arr3 = array([],int)
for i in range(len(arr1)):
    res = arr1[i] + arr2[i]
    arr3=np.append(arr3,res)
print(arr3)

Output :
[ 3 11 14 16 ]
```

Or you can use numpy.nditer to iterate over arrays and append it to the new array

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
arr1 = array([2,8,9,7])
arr2 = array([1,3,5,9])


arr3 = array([],int)

for x, y in zip(np.nditer(arr1),np.nditer(arr2)):
    arr3 = np.append(arr3,x+y)

print(arr3)

Output :
[ 3 11 14 16 ]
```

If you want it so simple then you can just add it

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
arr1 = array([2,8,9,7])
arr2 = array([1,3,5,9])
arr3 = arr1+arr2
print(arr3)

Output :
[ 3 11 14 16 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
arr3 = arr1+arr2
```

or, in case arr3 already contains data and you really want to append:

```
arr3 = append(arr3, arr1+arr2)
```